# Local login fails with HPE RESTful Interface Tool "ilorest"

Tags: login, ilo, hpe

We have a problem with an HPE Proliant Gen 10 Server. When trying to login to iLO 5 locally from within a Linux OS via HPE's RESTful Interface Tool "ilorest", we get the message "Error: Could not authenticate. Invalid credentials, or bad username/password.".

That's strange since it should be possible to login from a locally installed OS without providing user credentials.

Example:

```
./ilorest login
iLOrest : RESTful Interface Tool version 2.2
Copyright (c) 2014, 2017 Hewlett Packard Enterprise Development LP

Validating...............................................................
Error: Could not authenticate. Invalid credentials, or bad username/password.
```

Our security setting in iLO 5 is set to "Production" (not HighSecurity or FIPS), so this isn't the problem.

Is there any other setting we have to enable in iLO, RBSU etc. to activate support for local logins via "ilorest" without user name and password?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong you want to access / change your ILO Functionalities from ILORest Tool and you are having trouble accessing it from local system.

Correct me if I got it wrong else you don't need to use login with ILORest just type ilorest as a command on shell and you will enter in another shell where you can update your BIOS/ILO settings.

*****]# ilorest

iLOrest : RESTful Interface Tool version 2.2

### Copyright (c) 2014, 2017 Hewlett Packard Enterprise Development LP**

iLOrest >

You need to authenticate while modifying these settings. 
You can use below mentioned link for help

https://hewlettpackard.github.io/python-redfish-utility/

Comment: We do need to authenticate locally to be able to modify iLO settings. Therefore, we have to use the command `ilorest login` as is described in the linked documentation: _If you are logging in to a local server, run the command (login) without arguments_. Also, HPE's own tools (e.g. firmware updates) use this command, too, and they produce the same error message. So we are wondering if there  is any setting we have to enable in iLO in order to be able to use such local logins.

Answer (score 0):

`ilorest --nologo login -u Administrator -p your_ilo_password`

For example:

```
echo '{"path": "/redfish/v1/Systems/1/BIOS/Settings/","body": {"Attributes": {"PowerRegulator": "DynamicPowerSavings"}}}' > PowerRegulator.json; ilorest --nologo rawpatch PowerRegulator.json
```

Comment: I edited for format, but you should give some information regarding the commands you are proposing.

Comment: We know it is possible to login locally (as well as remotely), if we provide a user name and a password. The question is: Why doesn't it work without a user name and a password? HPE's own documentation for `ilorest` states that local logins should be possible without providing user credentials (i.e. with just `ilorest login`). This does not work on our system. And, this breaks firmware update scripts from HPE, which also require local logins to work without user name and password.